# How do I change the timeout for an opening a WebSocket?

Tags: javascript, ios, websocket, mobile-safari, django-channels

Short and sweet:
How do I tell a WebSocket to stop or 'close' after attempting to open after a while?

I'm currently working on a Kahoot like web app where players can connect with their phones to play. The game uses completely vanilla JavaScript to run everything in the background and uses WebSockets to communicate with the django-channels game server. The game plays fine except for in scenarios where a player accidentally locks their phone or switches apps and closes their WebSocket. I can easily open a new connection but for some reason, in mobile safari, WebSockets take FOREVER to give up connecting.

For example:

1. A user connects on Wifi and opens a WebSocket
2. User disconnects from Wifi and drops the WebSocket without calling `.close` and properly closing the connection
3. User attempts to open new WebSocket without Wifi
4. User then connects to Wifi while previous WebSocket is still trying to connect

In my testing, the second WebSocket will try to connect for at least a minute before finally giving in and failing. Only then can I attempt to reconnect again and just exaggerates the whole process of reconnecting the player.

So like I asked above: how can I shorten this process? Is there a way to make the WebSocket give up sooner or am I doing this the wrong way?

If I need to add any more information, please let me know. This is my first time posting.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881957/websocket-connection-timeout) SO question?

Comment: What is the client development environment?  That's where you would inspect your webSocket interface to see what timeout or retry values it offers.  Is it just a browser?  Or something else?

Comment: @jfriend00 It's just two browsers: Chrome on Android and Safari on iOS. I've been looking around for timeout and retry values but haven't found much. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see a connection timeout mentioned anywhere in the [webSocket API specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/websockets/), nor can I find any mention in any webSocket documentation.  So, it appears you might have to implement your own.  Here's one way to do that:

```
function connectWebSocket(url, timeout) {
    timeout = timeout || 2000;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // Create WebSocket connection.
        const socket = new WebSocket(url);

        const timer = setTimeout(function() {
            reject(new Error("webSocket timeout"));
            done();
            socket.close();
        }, timeout);

        function done() {
            // cleanup all state here
            clearTimeout(timer);
            socket.removeEventListener('error', error);
        }

        function error(e) {
            reject(e);
            done();
        }

        socket.addEventListener('open', function() {
            resolve(socket);
            done();
        });
        socket.addEventListener('error', error);
    });
}

// Usage    
connectWebSocket(yourURL, 1000).then(function(socket) {
    socket.send("hello");
    // put other code that uses webSocket here
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Using your code works great to establish the WebSocket but I get `websocket.send is not a function` when calling `websocket.send` on the object that's returned by that function. Am I missing something?

Comment: @kawub - Since I don't have any variable in my recommended code named `websocket`, I have no idea what you're doing.  As always, I can only help with code I can see.  You could add your attempted code onto the end of your question so I can see it.  This function returns a promise, NOT a webSocket object.  You have to use that promise like I show to get the socket from it.